# Oracle SQL - Anniversaries that occur between two days ago and seven days from now

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been at this problem for an assignment for a few days now and I haven't been able to get a correct query to work. My instructor has been less than helpful. The question is as follows:

"You are asked to prepare a list of employee anniversaries that occur between two days ago and seven days from now. The list should retrieve rows from the EMPLOYEES table which include the EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, JOB_ID, and HIRE_DATE columns in ascending order based on the day and month components of the HIRE_DATE value. An additional expression aliased as ANNIVERSARY is required to return a descriptive message based on the following table. There are several approaches to solving this question.

**HIRING DAY**-------------------------**MESSAGE**
Two days ago------------------------Day before yesterday
One day ago-------------------------Yesterday
Today----------------------------------Today
Tomorrow-----------------------------Tomorrow
Two days in the future--------------Day after tomorrow
Within seven days from today----Later this week

Hint: Use CASE/WHEN, TO_CHAR AND TO_NUMBER FUNCTIONS
Your results will vary depending on which date you execute the query."

I have been able to come up with the following query but it does not take into account when it is the end of the year and the anniversary is in early January:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, JOB_ID, HIRE_DATE,
CASE  WHEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DDMM'),'DDMM') - TRUNC(SYSDATE) = -2 THEN 'Day before yesterday' 
      WHEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DDMM'),'DDMM') - TRUNC(SYSDATE) = -1 THEN 'Yesterday'
      WHEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DDMM'),'DDMM') - TRUNC(SYSDATE) = 0 THEN 'Today'
      WHEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DDMM'),'DDMM') - TRUNC(SYSDATE) = 1 THEN 'Tomorrow'
      WHEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DDMM'),'DDMM') - TRUNC(SYSDATE) = 2 THEN 'Day after tomorrow'
      WHEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE,'DDMM'),'DDMM') - TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN 2 AND 7 THEN 'Later this week'
      ELSE TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'MON-DD')
END
AS "ANNIVERSARY"
FROM EMPLOYEES
ORDER BY TO_CHAR(HIRE_DATE, 'MMDD');
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CASE expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) come into two flavors:

- Simple case expression: `CASE expr WHEN value THEN result WHEN value THEN result ...`
- Searched case expression: `CASE WHEN condition THEN result WHEN cond THEN result ...`

I am combining both, one returning the number of day difference (inner). This result is used as expression in the second (outer) case expression which determins the message.

The inner case expression handles two edge cases at year boundaries and one normal case.

```
SELECT CASE
  CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) = 1 AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM HIRE_DATE) = 12 THEN
    MAKEDATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)-1 12 EXTRACT(DAY FROM HIRE_DATE)) - TRUNC(SYSDATE)
  WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE) = 12 AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM HIRE_DATE) = 1 THEN
    MAKEDATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)+1 1 EXTRACT(DAY FROM HIRE_DATE)) - TRUNC(SYSDATE)
  ELSE
    MAKEDATE(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE) EXTRACT(MONTH FROM HIRE_DATE) EXTRACT(DAY FROM HIRE_DATE)) -
    TRUNC(SYSDATE)
  END
WHEN -2 THEN '...'
WHEN -1 THEN '...'
...
ELSE ...
END
```

Comment: I should have specified in the text that I am using Oracle 11g, it does not seem to recognize the DATESERIAL().

Comment: Apparently Oracle's `DateSerial(year, month, day)`equivalent  (found in other SQL dialects) is `MAKEDATE(year month day)` (without commas).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!